# How to use a component in place of ionic 4 <ion-tab>

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I currently have some tabs that just show some text right now (standard/hepatic content)

```
<ion-content padding class="white-bg">

  <ion-tabs #dosingTabs>

    <ion-tab tab="standard">standard content</ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tab="hepatic">hepatic Content</ion-tab>

    <ion-tab-bar slot="top" [selectedTab]="dosingType">
      <ion-tab-button tab="standard">
        <ion-label>Standard</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="hepatic">
        <ion-label>Hepatic<br>Impairment</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>

  </ion-tabs>

</ion-content>
```

The contents of these tabs will end up having a lot of markup in them so I created a new component and tried:

```
<ion-tab tab="standard" component="StandardComponent"></ion-tab>
```

When I go to my view that has the tabs, I get an error:

**No component factory found for StandardComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?**

So I adjusted my module to include `StandardComponent` in `entryComponents` array, but the error still exists

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CalculatorPage } from './calculator.page';
import { StandardComponent } from '../standard/standard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CalculatorPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    StandardComponent
  ]
})
export class CalculatorPageModule {}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some else runs into this problem, I think i found the solution (or at least a work around). If anyone can confirm this it would help.

My findings are that you **can't** invoke a modal like this:

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component : FilterPage,
  mode      : "md",
  componentProps: { }
});
```

The compontent 'FilterPage' isn't available within the Tab component. If you try it will cause an error that says:

```
"Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"
```

Adding it to the module or App module will not resolve this issue and this error message will keep showing up.

**The solution** I found is quite simple but took me hours of my life. Invoke the Modal like this:

```
var modal = this.modalController.create(FilterPage); 
return await modal.present();
```

I think this way Ionic isn't trying to pass a component but a Page instead.

Note: This was in Ionic v4 table (ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.1)

Comment: good to know, thank you. I never resolved this and ended up not using tabs

Comment: Add it to the entry components not to the declarations

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the component to the declarations array as well inorder to get registered

```
declarations : [
  StandardComponent
]
```

Comment: hmm, still getting the error after adding that. Do I need to adjust anything in the app.module.ts file? It looks like when I created the component via the CLI, it added StandardComponent to the declarations array already. Currently I am working in that calculator page

Comment: which module calculator page belongs to?

Comment: you need to add the StandardComponent under delarationsof calculatorPageModule and also export it

Comment: I believe I had done that and same error. This is what my calculator.module looks like now https://pastebin.com/BM245mD4

Comment: move your entryComponents to app.module and try

Comment: app.module.ts looks like this https://pastebin.com/dTT2xEFj and same error. I also removed the declarations and entryComponents from the CalculatorPageModule as well, but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass component as the @input property to 'ion-tab'. It should be loaded based on routing. Please refer this below link explains 'ion-tabs' configuration.

https://ionicacademy.com/tab-bar-ionic-4/

Comment: If my tabs are in a modal and the route never changes(because modals dont have routes as I understand), how can I get that working?